# Inter module call

Tags: assembly

Is it possible to call a function residing in another module without using an extra jump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Intermodular calls can be made via relative calls, of course you need to adjust the relativity at runtime. I've done this many times for runtime dynamic patching.